# Buttons within Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation

I'm fairly new to Android development, and I'm trying to customize a Navigation Drawer with 4 buttons, which I then want to customize in their looks, similar to what VSCO Cam does, but without the header image and just 4 buttons that take up all the space in the navigation drawer.

What I'm doing right now is creating a Drawer Layout using a FrameLayout for the main content and a LinearLayout for the Drawer. I then placed 4 Buttons in that Linear Layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--  The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Sidemenu (Navigation Drawer) -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lend_return"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/lend_return"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_inv_order"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/manage_inventory"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_inventar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/inventory"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/add_user"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For the Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // constants for db
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sync_gateway";
    public static final String designDocName = "sync_gateway-local";
    public static final String byDateViewName = "byDate";
    public static final String SYNC_URL = "http://141.45.176.157:4984/sync_gateway";
    // couchbase internals
    protected static Manager manager;
    //private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private static CharSequence mTitle;


    //Fragments
    FragmentWelcome fragmentWelcome = new FragmentWelcome("Welcome", R.layout.fragment_welcome);
    private Database database;
    private LiveQuery liveQuery;
    // UI
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle; //Used in the example, to be removed in final
    private LinearLayout mDrawerLinear; //To use Custom Buttons, I guess we need to use ImageView instead of ListView
    Button btn_lend_return;
    Button btn_inv_order;
    Button btn_inventar;
    Button btn_add_user;
    //private String[] mNavigationTitles;

    final String TAG = "VerleihSystem";
    FragmentLendReturn fragmentLendReturn = new FragmentLendReturn("Ausleihe/Rückgabe", R.layout.fragment_ausleihe__rueckgabe);
    FragmentInvOrder fragmentInvOrder = new FragmentInvOrder("Bestand verwalten", R.layout.fragment_bestand_verwalten);
    FragmentInventar fragmentInventar = new FragmentInventar("Bestand", R.layout.fragment_bestand);
    FragmentAddUser fragmentAddUser = new FragmentAddUser("User hinzufuegen", R.layout.fragment_user_hinzufuegen);

    public static void setDrawerTitle(String title) {
         mTitle = title;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //mNavigationTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_array);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        View.OnClickListener buttonHandler = new DrawerItemClickListener();

        btn_lend_return = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lend_return);
        btn_inv_order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_inv_order);
        btn_inventar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_inventar);
        btn_add_user = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_user);
        btn_lend_return.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
        btn_inv_order.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
        btn_inventar.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
        btn_add_user.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens TODO
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);


        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        // TODO: Speak with Group about this, propably needs to be removed so that no
        // ActionBar App Icon exists

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        //ActionBarDrawerToggle for interactions between sliding the drawer and the app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                    // Host Activity(Context)
            mDrawerLayout,            // DrawerLayout Object
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentWelcome);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }


    //Click listener for the ListView in the Drawer

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onButton(View v) {
        //update the main content by replacing Fragments in the main View "view"
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_lend_return:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentLendReturn);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_inv_order:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentInvOrder);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_inventar:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentInventar);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_add_user:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentAddUser);
            break;
        }

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        //update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        setTitle(mTitle);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        //mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     * <p/>
     * STRAIGHT EXAMPLE COPY, I have no Idea what this does
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButton(v);
        }
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is use 4 Buttons as a navigation to change the fragments, and I'm trying to use the buttons instead of a list view because I only use 4 navigation elements, so I can make them take 1/4 of the space in the navigation drawer.

However, executing this code gives me an error saying that my LinearLayout is not  a sliding drawer.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{b2d82ec0 V.E.....    ........ 0,0-480,618 #7f08003e app:id/left_drawer} is not a sliding drawer
```

I've only found one other person having the same problem, but they have solved it by replacing 
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
with the correct Drawer Layout, which is something I have already done.

EDIT: What I forgot to add is that it does start, but with the linear layout layered above the content fragment, filling the whole screen and being a bit translucent:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ3lg.jpg

Whenever you click sth like the toggle or one of the buttons it crashes.

Does anyone know what I did wrong? If there is another, better way to do it, I'm always open for that! :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't the drawer be a `ListView` **always**

Comment: @HipHopDroid it does not have to be a listview

Comment: Ok. I will keep that in mind now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out myself:

The Navigation Drawer needs a layout_gravity instead of gravity, so everything works fine now.

```
<!-- Sidemenu (Navigation Drawer) -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left">
```